# Rails 4 to pull files from folder and push to s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, amazon-s3

I am using Rails 4. I need to create a project which can pull the files from a folder present in my system and push those files to s3 bucket one by one. After it is retrieved and pushed to s3,  I want those files to be deleted from the folder. I want this entire thing to be in a while() loop so that the loop is always checking for files in the folder.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend [Fog](http://fog.io) for that purpose. Its a great gem.
Following is code using fog:

```
fog = Fog::Compute.new(
      :provider => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id => 'YOUR KEY',
      :aws_secret_access_key => 'YOUR SEC KEY'
    )   


directory = fog.directories.create(
  :key    => "BUCKET NAME", 
  :public => true
)

fog.put_object("BUCKET NAME", key, File.open('/your/file/location'))

File.delete('/your/file/location')
```

Put it in the loop as per your requirements